# Blender, video sequencer, insert keyframes for transform.offset by script

Tags: python, blender

Is it possible to insert keyframes for transform.offset_x (or _y) property via python script. I want to insert position key frames for all image strips in sequencer. I tried the code below but got na error "TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "transform.offset_x" not found".

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
queue = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
for i in queue:
    itemType = i.type
    itemLead = i.frame_offset_start + i.frame_start
    if itemType == "IMAGE":
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path='transform.offset_x', frame=itemLead)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform.keyframe_insert(data_path='offset_x')` instead of a `data_path` of `'transform.offset_x'`

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
queue = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
for i in queue:
    itemType = i.type
    itemLead = i.frame_offset_start + i.frame_start
    if itemType == "IMAGE":
        i.transform.keyframe_insert(data_path='offset_x', frame=itemLead)
```